# Fast way for matrix multiplication in Python

Tags: python, matrix-multiplication, dot-product

Does anybody know a fast way to compute matrices such as:

```
Z{i,j}  = \sum_{p,k,l,q} \frac{A_{ip} B_{pk} C_{kl} D_{lq} E_{qj} }{a_p - b_q - c}
```

[image]

For normal matrix multiplication I would use `numpy.dot(a,b),` but now I got to divide the  elements by `$a_p$` and `$b_q$`.

Any suggestions?

Any suggestions on how to compute

```
$$ C_{i,j} =  \sum _p = \frac{E_{i,p} B_{p,j}}{m_p} $$
```

will be of great help as well.

Comment: what kind of a matrix is that?

Comment: it is a two dimensional matrix. Also the matrices A,B, C, D and E are two dimensional

Comment: Are you sure it is b_q? q is used to index D and E and as far as I see, it can even be outside the indices of B (for instance, D can be 2X40 and E 40 X 2, A, B and C can be 2 X 2, which would make a q of 3 outside the scope of B). BTW, please edit the code for second formula, for us to see it as the first one.

Comment: @rlinden, yes I am sure it's b_q. I am sorry but I don't know how to edit the code, someone else did that.  Matrices A,B,C,D and E all have the same shape ( n x n ) and the length of a and b is n.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `(E[i, p] * B[p, j]) / m[p]` is equal to `E[i, p] * (B[p, j] / m[p])`, so you can simply divide `m` into `B` before calling `np.dot`.

```
def f(E, B, m):
    B = np.asarray(B)  # matrix
    m = np.asarray(m).reshape((B.shape[0], 1))  # row vector
    return np.dot(E, B / m)  # m is broadcasted to match B
```